# 4 x 4 Characteristic Values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For $V = \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ the vector space of $4 \times 4$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, we're given that the matrix $$B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ and we define $T_B: V \to V$ by $T_B(A) = BA - AB$ for each $A \in V$. We want to find all eigenvalues of $T_B$ and the dimension of the associated eigenspace to each eigenvalue. I've found the matrix of $xI - (BA - AB)$ to be $$\begin{bmatrix}
x & A_{12} & 2A_{13} & 3A_{14} \\
-A_{21} & x & A_{23} & 2A_{24} \\
-2A_{31} & -A_{32} & x & A_{34} \\
-3A_{41} & -2A_{42} & -A_{43} & x \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach the problem, as I'm having serious difficulty finding the eigenvalues from here. Any hints or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably not the best approach. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T_B$, then there exists $A$ with $$BA-AB=\lambda A.$$ That is, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-A_{12}&-2A_{13}&-3A_{14}\\ 
A_{21}&0&-A_{23}&-2A_{24}\\ 
2A_{31}&A_{32}&0&-A_{34}\\ 
3A_{41}&2A_{42}&A_{43}&0\\ 
 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda\,A_{11}&\lambda\,A_{12}&\lambda\,A_{13}&\lambda\,A_{14}\\ 
\lambda\,A_{21}&\lambda\,A_{22}&\lambda\,A_{23}&\lambda\,A_{24}\\ 
\lambda\,A_{31}&\lambda\,A_{32}&\lambda\,A_{33}&\lambda\,A_{34}\\ 
\lambda\,A_{41}&\lambda\,A_{42}&\lambda\,A_{43}&\lambda\,A_{44}\\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

If $\lambda=0$, we get that $A$ is diagonal.

If $\lambda\ne0$, then $A_{11}=A_{22}=A_{33}=A_{44}=0$. If $A_{12}\ne0$, then $\lambda=-1$. If $A_{21}\ne0$, then $\lambda=1$. If $A_{13}\ne0$, then $\lambda=-2$, and $\lambda=2$ if $A_{31}\ne0$. In a similar way we obtain $\lambda=\pm3$. So the eigenvalues are 
$$
\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}.
$$

For the dimensions:

- $\lambda=0$: the eigenvectors are the diagonal matrices, so the dimension of the eigenspace is $4$.
- $\lambda=1$: this forces all coefficients to be equal to zero with the exception of $A_{21}$, $A_{32}$, and $A_{43}$. So the dimension of the eigenspace is $3$.

-$\lambda=2$: here only $A_{31}$ and $A_{42}$ can be nonzero, so the eigenspace has dimension $2$.

- $\lambda=3$: on $A_{41}$ can be nonzero, so the dimension of the eigenspace is $1$.
- For the negative eigenvalues the logic is similar.

In summary, the eigenvalues are $\lambda\in\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$ and the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $4-|\lambda|$.